# Cordova on iOS - Some images load others don't

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I have a Cordova app that I'm testing on iOS. When I launch the app, the login screen appears and contains two images: background and a logo. The background image loads fine, but the logo doesn't load until after I switch to a different page and then go back to the login page.

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image: Screen with both]

The image is bundled by webpack, and it loads/renders fine in the the browser. Why are some images loading correctly while others aren't? They're all `png` images being resolved by webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by react-router. According to a bunch of answers I found, `HashRouter` should work in Cordova, but that's what I was already using, so I switched to [`MemoryRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md) and my images are now loading properly.